# How do I change the order in which grep looks for pattern in files by filename

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I have a directory with a bunch of files with numerical filenames like this:

1 - filename
2 - filename
3 - filename
etc...

They don't have leading zeroes, so if I do something like

```
grep -oha "pattern" "/Users/test/Downloads/dir" -r
```

I might get something like this (filenames are just to show order in which grep searches pattern in files):

3 - filename:result
1 - filename:result
2 - filename:result

I'd rather have the result be like this:

1 - filename:result
2 - filename:result
3 - filename:result

Comment: Will this sort ouptut or files order in which grep will search? I do not need sort file content, just files order in which grep then will search. So basically I need grep to search files in this order: '1 - filename', '2 - filename', '3 - filename' etc...

Comment: I somewhere have seen that there are such possability. If not, could you please give example in code how this can be done? I am newbie and have had hard time to even make grep command I needed to search something in those files...

Comment: Why are you trying to modify the search order of grep, rather than using `sort` on the result?

Comment: Because I need lines in files stay in order they are. For example in each file I have 2-5 needed patterns (f.e. example.com). Files also are in their own order with numbers at the start of filename. So I need output where all found patterns are in order of filenames in which grep is searching.

Comment: If you sort the output , you will get all the files in correct groups, but within a group, the lines will be sorted which you do not want. Hence there are some ways to try that : [[1]] use `find` to generate the list of files , then use `sort` , then give that list to `grep` , either [[1A]] on the commandline or [[1B]] using a `for` loop [[2]] use `grep` , then use `sort` on the `grep` output , but limit that to sorting till the `:` character.

Comment: I not actually understood what you wrote, but you gave me simple idea - remove -h flag from my grep - so now all output search results have filenames in the beginning and I can use that to order results in Excel.

Comment: That is what I was conveying : limit the sorting till the ":" where the filename comes before the ":" & the Part after the ":" is the matching line which will be in the original order. You can get this through command-line itself, but if your workflow involves Excel , then you can go with that.

Comment: This is the **simple command-line** I was talking about **[[ `grep -oHa "pattern" "/Users/test/Downloads/dir" -r | sort -s -t : -k 1` ]]** where `-H` is to include the filename , `-s` is to use stable sorting , `-t` takes ":" Delimiter & `-k 1` takes the Part before ":" to sort.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `-h` flag from `grep`. Now all output search results have filenames in the beginning and you can use that to order results in Excel.

This is not actually an answer to the explicit question but at least you can achieve results in this way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).